# Screenshot of a windorws form and save it by savefiledialog

Tags: c#, android, winforms

I am a newbee and trying to get a screenshot of my active windows form application and save it to a folder which I can choose (with savefiledialog). 
None of the solutions here could help me.

I simply want to add a button on my application and when I click it, It should give me a save dialog screen and save ONLY my form to the folder which I can choose with the name which I can choose. I am not interested in full screen capture.

Also, can I get this image in high quality?

Comment: This is a lot of questions in one shot, making it too broad for the SO Q&A format.  Read:  [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2):

```
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
        DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size));

        SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog()
        if(saveDialog.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(saveDialog.FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                bmp.Save(fs, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Works great except for one thing: when Save Dialog opens, you can give it a name, but can't choose format, so it's saved as a file without extension.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a panel and placed everything how I wanted it.

this code works perfectly for me

```
private void Snipbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
    panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, panel1.Width, panel1.Height));

    SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();

    // image filters  
    saveDialog.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp";

    if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(saveDialog.FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            bmp.Save(fs, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).